Отображение шаблона записи
Имеется шаблон для записей на Elementor, однако не могу найти, где можно шаблон применить. Подскажите где можно изменить правило отображения?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
